# Proxypass not functioning "500 internal server error"

Tags: apache-2.2, proxypass

I am annoyed at having to constantly type in mydomain.com:10000 to access an application I have.
I read on here that you can set up proxypass so I can get app.mydomain.com to serve up mydomain.com:10000so its simple and I don't have to type in the port every time.

I set up the config as per [this thread on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/695686/redirect-subdomains-to-services-on-different-ports-of-same-server) but when I try to access it I get the following error

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.

Here is my config.

please let me know if any other info needs to be provided. I am kinda stumped as every guide I find points to this being an ok config. Unless I'm missing something

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app.mydomain.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://app.mydomain.com:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://app.mydomain.com:10000/
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

EDIT: fixed it, I just added the following to my config

```
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
```

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it. But please don't edit the solution into your question, instead post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question stays in the system at unsolved forever.